# Delete/update and generate a tkinter label on button click in the same function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a password generator with tkinter. Everything works fine except one thing:
When generate the password and write it to a label in the same function I get a new label every time I click the button that starts the function.

**I am aware similar problems have been treated already but none of the answers to other posts fully fit my intentions.**

I have the following code:

```
import string
import random
import tkinter as tk

letters = string.ascii_letters
numbers = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation

chars, nums, syms = True, True, True

evy = ""

if chars:
    evy += letters
if nums:
    evy += numbers
if syms:
    evy += symbols

length = 8

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Password Generator")
window.configure(background="black")
window.resizable(False, False)


def generate():
    for x in range(1):
        global password
        password = "".join(random.sample(evy, length))
        pwd = tk.Label(text=password, foreground="green", background="black", font=16)
        pwd.pack()


genBtn = tk.Button(window, command=generate, text="Generate Password")
genBtn.pack(anchor=tk.NE)


def copy_clip():
    if password:
        window.clipboard_clear()
        window.clipboard_append(password)
        window.update()


copyBtn = tk.Button(text="Copy the password", command=copy_clip)
copyBtn.pack(anchor=tk.NE)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Create the label once outside the function and update its text inside the function.  What is the point of the for loop that iterates only once?

Comment: You get a new label because you explicitly create a new label.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that you create a new label widget every time you click the "Generate Password" button, which leads to multiple labels being stacked on top of each other. To fix this, you should create the label widget outside the generate function and then update its text when the password is generated. Here's the modified code:

```
import string
import random
import tkinter as tk

letters = string.ascii_letters
numbers = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation

chars, nums, syms = True, True, True

evy = ""

if chars:
    evy += letters
if nums:
    evy += numbers
if syms:
    evy += symbols

length = 8

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Password Generator")
window.configure(background="black")
window.resizable(False, False)

password_label = tk.Label(text="", foreground="green", background="black", font=16)
password_label.pack()

def generate():
    global password
    password = "".join(random.sample(evy, length))
    password_label.config(text=password)

genBtn = tk.Button(window, command=generate, text="Generate Password")
genBtn.pack(anchor=tk.NE)

def copy_clip():
    if password:
        window.clipboard_clear()
        window.clipboard_append(password)
        window.update()

copyBtn = tk.Button(text="Copy the password", command=copy_clip)
copyBtn.pack(anchor=tk.NE)

window.mainloop()
```